# Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 2) - target folders not allowed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

While trying to commit the /trunk, I'm getting the following error:

```
Sending content      : E:\something\abc.log
Error                : Commit failed (details follow):
Error                : Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 2) with output:
Error                : trunk/thefolder1/folder2/target/ - target folders not
Error                :  allowed
```

I've searched the web for the error and wasn't able to find a solution. Before the commit I checked option `all`.(i.e. non-versioned also included in the commit)

I use TortoiseSVN 1.7.11 (Subversion 1.7.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository you commit to has a custom hook script which does not allow you to perform this particular commit. Ask your Subversion server / repository administrator why this commit is considered invalid.

My guess is that the word `target` in path is not allowed in the repository, but your administrator knows what's going on for sure.

Comment: You are correct. We cannot commit `target` folder. I did an `mvn clean` and next time all the target files were unchecked.The commit then worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is an appropriate answer but generally the Server commits are administered by the Configuration Management team(CM). The roles are assigned by them depending on the purpose. 
409 error is generally thrown when the server refuses to commit your change either because:
1. They have assigned a standard to check-in with a specific commit pattern. 
For example: for me it is [**ArtifactXXXX]*Username* Details**].
Check with the CM team regarding any 409 errors.